# Refresh entire RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, recyclerview-layout

How to update entire RecyclerView. I tried notifyDataSetChanged() but it update only visible positions. But i want to update enitre RecyclerView.

I tried adapter.notifyItemRangeChanged(0, adapter.getItemCount()); but this one is also not refreshing entire RecyclerView.

I need RecyclerView position start from 0 to Total count while refreshing data because based on position data is fetching.

```
public class HLVAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<HLVAdapter.ViewHolder>  {

    ArrayList<Model_Pager> arrayList;

    Activity activity;

    static ViewHolder viewHolder;
 
    SettingApiSave cust_setting;

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position, List<Object> payloads) {
        super.onBindViewHolder(holder, position, payloads);

        Log.v("HLVCategoryAdapter","position:"+position);
    }

    public HLVAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<Model_Pager> arrayList) {
        super();
        this.activity = activity;
        this.arrayList = arrayList;
        

    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.category_list_item, viewGroup, false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);

        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder viewHolder, final int i) {

        HLVAdapter.viewHolder = viewHolder;
   
        Log.e("car_nameeeeee", "i:  " + save_add.getString("name" + i, ""));
       


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return UberMapFragment.Total_Category;
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener, View.OnLongClickListener {

  
        public RelativeLayout lay_rel_img;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            lay_rel_img = (RelativeLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.lay_rel_img);

          
         
        }
      
       
    }
  

}
```

This is recyclview  i declared.

```
   mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
   
    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), 
    LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
```

And i update recycleview with  mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

Please any one suggest me any solution.Thank you

[image: recyclewview]

Comment: Add more code plz!

Comment: `notifyDataSetChanged` uses the adapter, not "visible positions"

Comment: yes, while i used notifyDataSetChanged() i update only those position which is visible in screen. if i scroll to 3 position then it start to update with three position only

Comment: means whatever positions visible that one only update

Comment: No it would refresh ur entire recycler view,Notify data set changed is the potential solution to ur problem

Comment: How do you control visibility? You mean elements off the screen? I'm telling you that notifyDataSetChanged (should) also refresh those

Comment: add some code mate

Comment: did you try recyclerView.invalidate() ?

Comment: no, this one will work for me? can i use it instead of notifyDataSetChanged()?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, it's not possible because recycler view doesn't have whole data it binds on the scroll so u can't refresh whole recycled view with notifyItemRangeChanged(0, adapter.getItemCount()); or any of this notify property.Recycler view has only data which are available in the view.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution is to recreate your recycleView. 
But Why you need update that items are not showing?

Comment: My problem is position only. i  am fetching data from SharePreference with position only. so i need position from 0 to last item and i need to update it